# Unity: Slow deployment to Android devices?

Tags: unity, android, deployment

From the time I hit "Build & Run", I wait 2 minutes (each) for Unity 5 to push to two different 'Droids. Fresh project, one script to generate a simple mesh, and no other assets. I am deploying via a USB 2.0 port.

IIRC from using Unity 4 in 2012, the same was true then, including for iOS deployments.

Is this to be expected? My dev machine is an i7 with 16GB RAM and everything else is fast.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way... But, how big are your assets?

Comment: @Byte56 No, this is the thing - it's an "empty" executable :) See edit.

Comment: Huh. I haven't tried it myself. I'll wait for someone more experienced to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to need to wait a while when you want to actually test your game on the device, since it doesn't only include sending the data over USB cable. They probably count the time it takes to instal the game in the "pushing" process.
That's why you can use the Editor and Unity Remote (it's on the play store) for instant testing.

Btw an empty Unity game also has a considerable size. If you're concerned about the time it takes for Unity to send the game to the device you should build the game and move it to the phone by yourself to compare the time.

Comment: I knew about the size (contains Unity packages), and I knew _of_ Unity Remote (though never used it). IIRC, I used to manually copy to the device.  Would you say this / Remote is the more standard approach? As I can't imagine most devs being willing to wait so long for deployment on average... unless a habit is made of testing in the Editor and only occasionally deploying, which would seem quite restrictive.

Comment: Well if it takes you long to deploy why not just use Remote when making small changes? From my experience it has good enough capabilities for this. Although I do think it would have been great if we could just deploy instantly.

Comment: From research I've done elsewhere, I can see this is literally as good as it gets right now - this and accepting that for larger games, you will only be deploying occasionally, due to sheer time taken to build / deploy, and most testing will need to be done on a fast emulator or the desktop build. Checkmark is yours.